# How do I retrieve all parameters and its values in a URL?

Tags: php, url

If I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3 (an example)
```

I am working on a project and want to see what parameters are passing to a URL internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array:

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET as $paramKey => $paramValue) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = array();
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);

// $query['a'] = 1, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to see what is being passed and how PHP is handling your GET values, the simplest method would be:

```
<?
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several sources for that:

- [`$_GET`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is an array of the already parsed query string. In your case:

  ```
  array('a'=>'1', 'b'=>'2', 'c'=>'3')
  ```
- [`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is the raw query string. In your case:

  ```
  'a=1&b=2&c=3'
  ```
- [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains the requested URL path plus the query. In your case:

  ```
  '/?a=1&b=2&c=3'
  ```